How to send simple email with curl
Over three days I have read hundreds of posts on using curl to send basic smtp email.  I started with using mail, which ends up using exim4 on my system (Debian Linux), but it didn't work and I get almost no information using -d or -v options, so gave that up.
My latest attempt that comes closest to success is based on this answer.
Curl tells me it is able to connect to the server, establish a TLS connection, and successfully authenticate.  Then it tells me the URL is no good, which seems to be its answer to every problem and doesn't make sense. And of course I don't get the email. I've tried countless variations on quotes etc.  Here is my best curl attempt and the output (email addresses and password redacted):
#!/usr/bin/zsh

SMTP='mail.forestpathology.org'
PORT=465  # SSL/TLS is port 465; non-SSL is 2525
USER='------@forestpathology.org'
PASS='-------'
SERVER='Tabernacle'
FROM='-----@forestpathology.org'
TO='-----@mac.com'

cat mail.txt

curl -v --ssl-reqd \
--url smtps://$SMTP:$PORT \
--user $USER:$PASS \ 
--mail-from $FROM \
--mail-rcpt $TO \
--upload-file mail.txt

Tabernacle:~$ sudo bin/testsm.zsh

From: "User Name" <-----@forestpathology.org>
To: "John Smith" <-----@mac.com>
Subject: This is a test

Hi John,
I’m sending this mail with curl.
Bye!

*   Trying 70.32.23.63:465...
* Connected to mail.forestpathology.org (70.32.23.63) port 465 (#0)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=forestpathology.org
*  start date: May 26 20:05:10 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 24 20:05:09 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "mail.forestpathology.org" matched cert's "mail.forestpathology.org"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
< 220-mi3-ss52.a2hosting.com ESMTP Exim 4.96.2 #2 Tue, 28 May 2024 16:47:53 -0400 
< 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
< 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
> EHLO Tabernacle
< 250-mi3-ss52.a2hosting.com Hello Tabernacle [97.120.128.182]
< 250-SIZE 78643200
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-PIPECONNECT
< 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
< 250 HELP
> AUTH PLAIN
< 334 
> AG----------------------------XM=
< 235 Authentication succeeded
> HELP
< 214-Commands supported:
214-Commands supported:
< 214 AUTH HELO EHLO MAIL RCPT DATA BDAT NOOP QUIT RSET HELP
214 AUTH HELO EHLO MAIL RCPT DATA BDAT NOOP QUIT RSET HELP
* Connection #0 to host mail.forestpathology.org left intact
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
Tabernacle:~$ 


Why would you use sudo to run a script which doesn't contain any privileged commands?

Your mail.txt appears to begin with an empty line, making it not a valid SMTP message.

Does this answer your question? Using curl to send email

@tripleee, I added the blank line just to make the output look cleaner, but removing it and running without sudo gave same result.  I actually used the question you linked as a model for my attempt, so no, it doesn't answer my question.  I also attempted using a gmail account as in that question, but gmail denied login and at the end curl still gave the same error about bad URL!  I think gmail has heightened security since that question.

I found the problem.  I'm not allowed to say where I got the solution, but I was stunned to get the correct answer. The problem was a space after one of the \ end-of-line characters, which a human is unlikely to see.  After I deleted the space, the email was sent successfully.
I was unaware that such spaces would mess up the command.
